# PHP - Generate all possible permutations and do something

Tags: php, permutation

I have a set of value, say:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
```

and I'd like to generate all possible keys of 8-digit:

```
00000000
00000001
00000002
...
zzzzzzzy
zzzzzzzz
```

but all solutions found trying to allocate an array and PHP gets out of memory.

So I'd like to do something:

```
 // LOOPS
 // generate 1 permutation
 // do something
 // END LOOP
```

Any hints?

Comment: Use [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) instead of arrays. But be aware that 36^8 == 2,821,109,907,456 so whatever you plan to do with that data it's going to take a _while_. Honestly it would be better if told us what "do something" is so that we could suggest a better way to do _that_. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @JensV I will ask you to retract that dupe close vote -- this question is clearly not seeking a unique random string.

Comment: Retracted, I guess I misinterpreted what he wanted to do. Reading again I guess the goal is to loop and always get the *next* permutation. Using a generator should indeed work nicely here.

Comment: You can remove your comment about the dupe recommendation too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate each and every possible combination of that list, up to a certain number of digits, then you can do this by using a power relation and a modulo.

For iteration `$i`, the index of the last digit is given by `$i % $numValues`

For iteration `$i`, the index of the last-but-one digit is given by `intval($i / $numValues) % $numValues`

For iteration `$i`, the index of the last-but-two digit is given by `intval($i / ($numValues * $numValues)) % $numValues`

For iteration `$i`, the index of the last-but-three digit is given by `intval($i / ($numValues * $numValues * $numValues)) % $numValues`

... and so on.

Generalising, you can then set this up as a loop:

```php
// list of values to use
$values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
$numValues = count($values);

// number of digits in each iteration
$numDigits = 8;

// total number of iterations
$numIterations = $numValues ** $numDigits - 1;

// main loop
for ($i = 0; $i <= $numIterations; $i++) {
    $str = '';
    // build string from the most significant digit (leftmost)
    // to the least significant digit (rightmost)
    for ($d = $numDigits - 1; $d >= 0; $d--) {
        $str .= $values[intval($i / ($numValues ** $d)) % $numValues];
    }
    // iteration is now in $str
    // do something with $str ...
    echo $str . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [base_convert()](https://php.net/base_convert) to convert from/to decimal and use a regular numeric loop:

```
echo base_convert('zzzzzzzz', 36, 10), PHP_EOL;
echo base_convert(2821109907455, 10, 36), PHP_EOL;
```

```
2821109907455
zzzzzzzz
```

Here's a simplified example (more on that below), using [printf()](https://php.net/printf) to add leading zeroes:

```
$to = base_convert('zzz', 36, 10);
for ($i = 0; $i < $to; $i++) {
    printf("%03s\n", base_convert($i, 10, 36));
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0eFNc)

The main is problem is that you're trying to generate a huge amount of data. Your alphabet has 36 characters, what makes a total of 36<sup>8</sup> possible strings (2,821,109,907,456) if I didn't mess maths. Your script is going to take really long to finish (high level interpreted languages are not ideal for speed), and you're going to have problems storing the information. You'll need to dump numbers on the go (to a file or database) and you'll need a very large disk.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using [generators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php), this makes using this function a bit easier, the algorithm to generate the numbers is pretty much the same as @Rob Eyre's:

```php
function permutations(array $charset, int $len) {
    $base = count($charset);
    $maxIterations = pow($base, $len);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $maxIterations; $i++) {
        $key = '';
        $currentValue = $i;

        for ($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++) {
            $digit = $currentValue % $base;
            $key = $charset[$digit] . $key;
            $currentValue = intdiv($currentValue, $base);
        }

        yield $key;
    }
}

// Using the generator, you can re-use the function easily without being memory-constrained
foreach (permutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 4) as $p) {
    echo "$p\n";
}
```

Comment: How much faster would you estimate this to be than Rob Eyre's version?

Comment: @HashimAziz the use of generators shouldn't have much of an impact on performance. The algorithm also has the same time complexity (BigO). Since we use slightly different operators and calculations, I think the only real way to check which is faster is to run a benchmark.

Comment: @HashimAziz its also trivial to convert Rob's solution into a generator function by wrapping everything into a function and replacing `echo` with `yield`